# CSS menu with 3 nested lists - align left problems

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a navigation menu with 3 sub levels. I need the 3rd level list to align left but I can't get it to behave. I can get levels 2 and 3 to align relatively with the main menu but I want the 2nd level to align relatively and the 3rd level aligning completely to the left. I'd appreciate any help/advice going, here is what I have:

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfrank44/u2shp/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK2</a>
    <ul class="#">
        <li><a href="#">LINK2a</a>
            <ul class="#">
            <li><a href="#">LINK2b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK2c</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK2d</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK2e</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK2f</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a, img { border:none; }
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.nav{
display:block;
list-style:none;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
height: 30px;
}
.nav li { 
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;    
border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.nav li a { 
width: 125px;
height: 30px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
z-index: 2000;      
background-color: #999;
}
li.active {
background-color: #999 ;
color: #000;
}
.nav li a:hover {
top: 30px;  
}
.nav li:hover > a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#333;  
}
.nav li ul { 
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;  
border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
left: -2px;
}
.nav li li:hover > a {
color:#000;
background-color:#999;  
}
.nav li li{ 
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
height: 25px;
}
.nav li li a {
height: 25px;
top: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 9px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #000;
z-index: 2000;      
background-color: #999;
}
li li.active {
background-color: #a9d9d9 ;
color: #007f7b;
}
.nav li li:hover ul {
left: -2px;
top: 25px; 
}
ul.nav li > ul {
width: 700px;
height: 25px;
background-color:blue;
}
ul.nav li > ul > li > ul {
background-color:red;
height: 25px; 
}
ul.nav li > ul > li { display: none; }
ul.nav li:hover li { display: block; }
```

Comment: Be more specific in the question please.

Comment: Hi Arun, apologies for not being clear. If you look at my jsfiddle, when you roll over link 2 - link 2a is in the correct place, links 2b-2f need to be aligned to the far left. I hope this is a bit clearer?

Comment: What do you mean "completely to the left"? Should the third level line up with Link 1? Link 2?

Comment: Thats correct, the third level should line up with Link 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are missing some simple changes CSS to make it work properly. I'll post what changes I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2shp/2/) to make it work:

`.nav li ul` became `.nav li > ul`

`.nav li:hover ul` became `.nav > li:hover > ul`

`.nav li li:hover ul` became `.nav li > li:hover ul`

`ul.nav li > ul > li { display: none; }` became `ul.nav li  ul ul { display: none; }`

`ul.nav li:hover li { display: block; }` became `ul.nav li:hover > ul { display: block; }`

Added:

```
ul.nav li ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    left: -129px;
}
ul.nav li li:hover > a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #333
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Giovanni, any ideas on moving the third level over to the left inline with Link 1?

Comment: Brilliant - thanks! Now I have to dissect what you've done and work out how you did it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I did change some stuff in there, like adding some `>` and removing others. I will try to see if I remember what I did and edit my post :)

Comment: Alright, all set. You should have all changes in the answer now :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks again, just going through it. If I wanted to add another drop down menu to link 5 I would have to change 'left: -129px' - can i add a class to this so the changes only affect the appropriate drop down?

Comment: No worries, sorted it - added a class to 'ul.nav li ul ul' - so it became - 'ul.nav li ul ul.submenu2' - Thanks again for your help!!!!

Comment: Considering that the 2nd level `ul` is `position:relative`, those 3rd level will always be relative to them, and not the main menu. So you would probably need to set some classes for each of those 3rd tier menus, and use `ul.nav li ul ul.menu2` and `ul.nav li ul ul.menu5` and so on, with different left values for them :)

Comment: Oh, seems you got it... Glad to hear :)